# How to fix: Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

Tags: reactjs, render

I am beginner to React and I am facing some problems. I am trying to get React to render one user, but I don't know how. Every attempt so far has been a failure and I really do need help.

[Error message and console.log(this.state.user)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tvOn.png)

```
class SelfEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
        user: null,
        loggedUser: props.loggedUser // Username of a logged account
    };

    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
}

render(){
    console.log(this.state.user);
    const div = (
        <div className="oneUser">
            <h2> {this.state.loggedUser} </h2> <br />
                 {this.state.user} //<-- Here I would like to get user's email or such
        </div>
    );
    return div;
}

getUser(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/' + this.state.loggedUser;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded : true,
                user: result
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded : true,
                error
            });
        }
    )
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.getUser();
}
}
```

So how can I make 'user' usable in the rendering?

Thank you in advance, now i have to go get some sleep.

Comment: The error message is quite descritive. React's render() method only works with components, not with objects. See https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow Dr.Pippis. As the error suggests, you simply cannot just render a javascript object as a React child. As is `this.state.user` is a raw object. React wants to interpret a string or number to display, so to do that you can use of the object's properties like email.

```
class SelfEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
        user: null,
        loggedUser: props.loggedUser // Username of a logged account
    };

    this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
}

render(){
    console.log(this.state.user);
    const div = (
        <div className="oneUser">
            <h2> {this.state.loggedUser} </h2> <br />
                 { this.state.user && (<div>{this.state.user.email}</div>) } 
        </div>
    );
    return div;
}

getUser(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/' + this.state.loggedUser;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded : true,
                user: result
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded : true,
                error
            });
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: Yessssssssss!!!!!!! Thank you so much, apparently I wasn't that far after all, I completely forgot to add { **this.state.user &&** (<div>{this.state.user.email}</div>) }  to check if it's null or not thus leading to an error in **{this.state.user.email}** cheers!

Comment: You're very welcome @Dr.Pippis! I'm glad I was able to nudge you in the right direction. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since user is an object you cannot render it as is. Instead need to either extract the properties you would like displayed before rendering them or reference them directly e.g.:

Directly:

```
render(){
  console.log(this.state.user);
  const div = (
    <div className="oneUser">
      <h2> {this.state.loggedUser} </h2>
      <div>{this.state.user.email}</div>
      <div>{this.state.user.username}</div>
    </div>
  );
  return div;
}
```

or extracted:

```
render(){
  console.log(this.state.user);
  // Destructure the properties you would like
  const {
    email,
    username,
  } = this.state.user;
  const div = (
    <div className="oneUser">
      <h2> {this.state.loggedUser} </h2>
      <div>{email}</div>
      <div>{username}</div>
    </div>
  );
  return div;
}
```